# Joining MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, sql

in my database there are 2 tables : posts, room

Posts tables include ID and Title columns and includes many rooms and hotels titles and IDs.

In the room table there are 3 columns : room_id, hotel_id and price where room_id and hotel_id are from Posts table.(ID column)

I want to run a query so I can see Hotel title, Room title, room_id(ID) and price in one table.

I can't figure out the correct join command. what code should I use?
thank you.

[image: Tables]

Comment: Found the answer here: [HOW TO JOIN SAME TABLE TWICE](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-join-same-table-twice/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the "hotel title" column comes from, but I'd try something like the following:

```
SELECT `posts`.`title`, `room`.`price`, `room`.`room_id`
FROM `posts` JOIN `hosts`
WHERE `posts`.`id` = `room`.`id`;
```

The `JOIN` clause will join the two tables, you then have to tell the query which columns match on each table. The result should be what you're looking for.

You can also create a `VIEW` so you don't need to run such a complex query each time:

```
CREATE VIEW myRooms AS
SELECT `posts`.`title`, `room`.`price`, `room`.`room_id`
FROM `posts` JOIN `hosts`
WHERE `posts`.`id` = `room`.`id`;
```

Then you just do:

```
SELECT * FROM myRooms;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your attention. both room and hotel titles are in the posts table and in the room table only their IDs(from posts table) are shown. I want to see the titles and prices in a table.

Comment: Then adjust the query from the one I provided. The important part is the `JOIN` clause, the `SELECT` part can be adjusted as needed.